# ¿Por qué el operador '==' retorna diferentes valores?

Tags: c++

Tengo miedo de que sea una pregunta tonta pero no logro entender por que el operador '==' me retorna verdadero y falso para dos expresiones parecidas o iguales:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    double d=0.3, dd=3;
    int i=3;
    cout<<"\"d*10==i\""<<" ::: "<<(d*10==i)<<endl;
    cout<<"\"dd==i\""<<" ::: "<<(dd==i)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

La salida es:

```
"d*10==i" ::: 0
"dd==i" ::: 1
```

Además cuando imprimo 'd*10' obtengo '3', no entiendo porque entonces cuando comparo 'd*10==i' (donde i=3) me devuelve falso, estoy un poco confundido.

Comment: El problema es de tipos. El manejo del "punto flotante" hace que sean diferentes ya que por ejemplo double d=0.0 e int dd =0  hace que d!=dd pues  d sera algo similar a 0.0000000000004 (no recuerdo con exactitud cuantos ceros después del punto) mientras que dd no tiene fracción decimal luego del punto (que estaría tácito) de modo que en tu caso 0.3 * 10 sería algo como 0.3000000000004 * 10 que es ligeramente mayor que 3. Para comparar números de tipos diferentes debes fijar antes un orden de magnitud significativo, hacer conversiones en el y luego comparar en su rango de valores.

Comment: gracias por tu comentario me ayudo a entender mejor y pude arreglarlo haciendo (fabs(d*10-i)<1e-9). Sin embargo tengo otra duda, ¿por qué cuando hago 'int k = 0.3*10' la salida al imprimir k es '3' pero cuando hago 'double d=0.3' y luego 'int k=d*10' la salida ahora es 2 al imprimir k, entiendo que k al ser int trunca los decimales pero en ese caso k no debería ser 3 y no 2?

Comment: En ese caso debe ser por el modelo de aproximación (es posible que redondee por debajo (algo así como 1.0 aprox 0.99999999999999, 3.0 aprox 2.999999999999999) y al cambiar de tipo se tiene que trunca la expansión decimal) puedes testear haciendo algo como convertir d + 0.000000000001 en lugar de convertir d, poniendo el 1 en la posición del rango de significación que necesites

Comment: (En el primer comentario use el dato de la representación de punto flotante en python. No caí en cuenta de que la representación en c puede aproximar por debajo)

Comment: tienes mucha razón, acabo de comprobarlo y todo tiene más sentido con lo que dices. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

He ejecutado tu código y lo que obtengo es:

```
"d*10==i" ::: 1
"dd==i" ::: 1
```

¿Estás seguro de que esa es la respuesta que obtienes? Lo único que se me ocurre que pueda estar pasando es que estás comparando un `double` con un `int`, quizá la comparación entre estos tipos te da falso por ese motivo.

P.D: no hay preguntas tontas!

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta:), he probado nuevamente mi código y me sigue saliendo falso para la primera línea de la salida, pero creo que como dices debe ser por la comparación de tipos, he podido arreglarlo haciendo: fabs(d*10-i)<1e-9, con eso ya me retorna verdadero

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, recuerda que las preguntas se realizan como comentarios, revisar [ask], saludos.